# How to get the ordered size of a product In Magento 2

Tags: magento2, orders, sales-order, order-items

I tried to get the size of a product/products that was ordered.

So let's say a product has 5 sizes: **S, M, L, XL,XLL** and when i made the order the `product x was bought with the size M`.

When i load the order i want to get this "M" size in my code.

This is how i load my order:

```
$order = $_objectManager->create('Magento\Sales\Model\Order')->load($orderID);

 foreach ($order->getAllItems() as $item) {
      $product = $_objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')->load($item->getProductId());
... here i want to get the size
}
```

**Does anyone know how to do that? because i didn't find nothing relevant.**

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try:

```
$order = $_objectManager->create('Magento\Sales\Model\Order')->load($orderID);

$items = $order->getAllVisibleItems();
// $items = $order->getAllItems(); // all items


foreach ($items as $item) {
    $options = $item->getProductOptions(); // all product options       
 }
```

**EDIT:**

If you can try not to use **ObjectManager** directly. It defeats the purpose of dependency injection.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
$order = $_objectManager->create('Magento\Sales\Model\Order')->load($orderID);
foreach ($order->getAllItems() as $item) {
     $productOptions = unserialize($item->getProductOptions());
     echo "<pre>";
     print_r($productOptions); 
     // check the [attributes_info] for the attributes info 
}
```

**OR**

```
$order = $_objectManager->create('Magento\Sales\Model\Order')->load($orderID);
foreach ($order->getAllItems() as $item) {
      $product = $item->getProduct();
      $size = $product->getSize(); // get size value
      if($product->getSize()) {
            echo $product->getAttributeText('size'); // get size label  
      }

}
```